# RadioButton check change not updating onPost: ASP.Net, Bootstrap HTML, C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have created two radio buttons, formed a group with them, and styled them with bootstrap classes. For some reason the radio buttons values are not being updated as I click one or the other and press submit. I also have checkboxes on this HTML form and those are being updated successfully.

I created boolean properties to represent the checked states of the checkboxes and radiobuttons and only the radio buttons are not changing from false to true when I click one and hit submit.

HTML for radio buttons and checkboxes:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-4  m-1">
                    <div class="row border border-dark-subtle rounded-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <label class="form-label mb-3 fw-bold fs-5">Details:</label>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.CompanyName required>
                            <label for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.CompanyName"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 align-content-center">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SerialNum" placeholder="Serial Number" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.SerialNum required>
                            <label for="SerialNum">Serial Number</label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.SerialNum"></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="mb-3">
                                <input class="form-check-input m-1" type="checkbox" id="HEX" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.Hex>
                                <label for="HEX" class="mb-3">HEX</label>
                         </div>   

                        <label class="form-label mb-2 fw-bold fs-5">License Level:</label><br />

                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                <input type="radio" class="btn-check m-1" name="licenseLevel" id="SMD" value="" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.SMD required>
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-1 mb-2" for="SMD">SMD + SM API</label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.SMD"></span>

                                <input type="radio" class="btn-check m-1 " name="licenseLevel" id="SmAPI" value="" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.SmApi>
                            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-1 mb-2" for="SmAPI"> SM API Enabled</label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.SmApi"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                
                </div>
                <div class="col border border-dark-subtle rounded-2 m-1">
                    <table>                      
                        <tr>
                                <label class="form-label mb-3 fw-bold fs-5">Features:</label>
                                
                        </tr>
                        <colgroup>
                            <col />
                            <col  />
                            <col  />
                        </colgroup>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:65%">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control w-50" id="BitEncoding" placeholder="Bit Encoding">
                                <label for="BitEncoding">Bit Encoding</label>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                            <td></td>

                            <td style="width:100%; text-align: right">
                            
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1">Select All</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1">Deselect All</button>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Automation" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.Automation>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="Automation">
                                Automation
                            </label>
                            <span style="font-weight:normal">
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li>MOTF</li>
                               <li>RS232</li>
                               <li>TCP/IP</li>
                               <li> DLL Automation</li>
                               <li>Database</li>
                            </ul>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="DynamicRendering" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.DynamicRendering>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="DynamicRendering">
                                Dynamic Rendering
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li>Text</li>
                               <li>Arc Text</li>
                               <li>Barcodes</li>
                               <li> Data Matrix</li>
                               <li>QR Code</li>
                               <li>PDF 417</li>
                               <li>Raster</li>
                               <li>Serial Number</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="DesignGroup" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.DesignGroup>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="DesignGroup">
                                Design Group
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li> Custom Canvas API</li>
                               <li>Vector File Reading API</li>
                               <li> Shape Operations API</li>
                                <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                                    <li>Shape Exploder</li>
                                    <li>Bounding Box Helper</li>
                                </ul>
                               <li>Scan Path Optimizer</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Processing" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.Processing>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="Processing">
                                3D Processing
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li>Surface Marking</li>
                               <li>Engraving</li>
                               <li> 3D Processing API (SMAPI)</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="AdvancedProcess" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.AdvancedProcess>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="AdvancedProcess">
                                Advanced Process
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li> Tiling</li>
                               <li>Tray Marking</li>
                               <li>Multi-ScanHead</li>
                               <li> HiRes Raster (PERC and Polygon)</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="MicroMachining" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.MicroMachining>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="MicroMachining">
                                Micro Machining
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li> SyncMaster (IFoP) </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col border border-dark rounded-3 m-1 mb-2">
                            <input class="form-check-input m-1" type="checkbox" id="VHD" asp-for=AddLicenseRequest.VHD>
                            <label class="mb-3 fw-bold" for="VHD">
                                VHD
                            </label>
                           <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                               <li> Drill Shape </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 mb-2">Generate License</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Properties established for checks/radios:

```
        public bool Hex { get; set; }

        public bool SmApi { get; set; }

        public bool SMD { get; set; }

        public bool Automation { get; set; }

        public bool DynamicRendering { get; set; }

        public bool DesignGroup { get; set; }

        public bool Processing { get; set; }

        public bool AdvancedProcess { get; set; }

        public bool MicroMachining { get; set; }

        public bool VHD { get; set; }
```

Backend C# handling the assigning of boolean values based on Binded submission:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult>OnPost() {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var license = new License()
                {
                    Hex = AddLicenseRequest.Hex,
                    SmApi = AddLicenseRequest.SmApi,
                    SMD = AddLicenseRequest.SMD,
                    CompanyName = AddLicenseRequest.CompanyName,
                    SerialNum = AddLicenseRequest.SerialNum,
                    Automation = AddLicenseRequest.Automation,
                    DynamicRendering = AddLicenseRequest.DynamicRendering,
                    DesignGroup = AddLicenseRequest.DesignGroup,
                    Processing = AddLicenseRequest.Processing,
                    AdvancedProcess = AddLicenseRequest.AdvancedProcess,
                    MicroMachining = AddLicenseRequest.MicroMachining,
                    VHD = AddLicenseRequest.VHD
                };

                license.BitEncoding = BitGenerator(license);

                await licenseRepository.AddAsync(license);

                var notification = new Notification
                {
                    Type = Enums.NotificationType.Success,
                    Message = "New license created!"

                };

                TempData["Notification"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(notification);

                return RedirectToPage("/admin/licenses/list");
            }

            return Page();
        }
```

I have tried creating different radio buttons and removing the bootstrap classes thinking that would solve something, but nothing has worked so far. I have seen a lot of solutions employing JavaScript and I'm not familiar with that language; I'm assuming there must be a way to solve this issue with C# and HTML so I would ideally like to stick to that.

My last resort would be to change them to checkboxes instead, but that is not the route I want to go so if anyone has any insight on how I can address this I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please see this link for radio usage in html. Take out the name attribute and submit your form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/408329/radio-button-not-passing-desired-values-to-my-cont

Comment: Removing the name has not solved anything for me, now I am running into issues with my ModelState no longer being valid and I believe it is because the name value connects the radio buttons within a group. I currently have the radiobutton fields as required, so with no name attribute both of the radio buttons have to be selected in order to successfully submit the form. However, the point of using radio buttons is so only one of them would be selected. Any ideas on how to keep them connected as a group with no name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be an issue with the **value attribute** in your radio buttons. The value attribute should be assigned a unique value for each radio button, and it should correspond to the value you want to assign to the respective boolean property in your backend C# code.

Currently, your radio buttons have `value=""`, which means they both have an empty value. This could be the reason why the values are not being updated as you click one or the other.

To fix this, you need to assign different values to each radio button. For example:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check m-1" name="licenseLevel" id="SMD" value="SMD" asp-for="AddLicenseRequest.SMD" required>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-1 mb-2" for="SMD">SMD + SM API</label>
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.SMD"></span>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check m-1 " name="licenseLevel" id="SmAPI" value="SmAPI" asp-for="AddLicenseRequest.SmApi">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-1 mb-2" for="SmAPI"> SM API Enabled</label>
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="AddLicenseRequest.SmApi"></span>
</div>
```

radio buttons work as a group, and only one of them can be selected at a time within that group. *By giving them different values*, the backend C# code will be able to determine which radio button was selected and update the corresponding boolean property accordingly.

Comment: This solution as well as removing the name property ended up working, thank you!